# Error Displaying Error page:Application installation Error in joomla 3.0

Tags: joomla

I am facing the problem in Joomla Component. I have attached the Screen in which I am facing the error.

I have made my own component for show time. When I add show using my component it works fine.Everything goes right but sometime I am getting this error.

When my client see this error, he gets hyper.

but do not know why this error comes.

Is there any solution?

Please help me guys.

Here is the screen shot of Error.

[image: Application installation Error]
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking that screen, I suppose the error is on the instance of the controller (that call the particular action) ... check if is it istantiate proprely. Also check the action calling... I suppose that is here the error..

Comment: I have put your solution in my component but this error not arise eventual..so will let you know if it will come again.